# SQLAlchemy: filter by membership in at least one many-to-many related table

Tags: python, mysql, many-to-many, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy 0.7.1 and a MySQL 5.1 database, I've got a many-to-many relationship set up as follows:

```
user_groups = Table('user_groups', Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', String(128), ForeignKey('users.username')),
    Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id'))
)

class ZKUser(Base, ZKTableAudit):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    username   = Column(String(128), primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String(512))
    last_name  = Column(String(512))

    groups = relationship(ZKGroup, secondary=user_groups, backref='users')

class ZKGroup(Base, ZKTableAudit):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'

    id          = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name        = Column(String(512))
```

Users can belong to multiple Groups, and Groups can contain multiple Users.

What I'm trying to do is build a SQLAlchemy query that returns only the Users who belong to at least one Group out of a list of Groups.

I played around with the `in_` function, but that only seems to work for testing scalar values for membership in a list.  I'm not much of a SQL writer, so I don't even know what kind of `SELECT` statement this would require.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

OK, after a lot of research, I realized that it was my own ignorance of SQL terminology that was holding me back.  My search for a solution to find users  belonging to "at least one of" the list of groups should have been to find users belonging to "any" of the list of groups.  The `any` ORM function from SQLAlchemy does exactly what I needed, like so:

```
session.query(ZKUser).filter(ZKUser.groups.any(ZKGroup.id.in_([1,2,3])))
```

That code emits this SQL (on MySQL 5.1):

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM user_groups, groups 
    WHERE users.id = user_groups.contact_id 
        AND groups.id = user_groups.group_id 
        AND groups.id IN (%s, %s, %s)
    )
```

Comment: How do filter by membership in at all many-to-many related table?

Comment: Your answer references `ZKContact` and `contacts`, but these aren't in your code in the question.  Did you mean ZKUser?

Comment: Down voting answer, it's using different keywords than question, and it's hard to follow what is possible solution.

Comment: @Drachenfels I fixed the naming inconsistency.

Comment: Awesome! SQLAlchemy continues to astound.

Comment: how can i do same thing with filter_by()

Answer (score 22):

According to [the docs for `any`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any), the query will run faster if you use an explicit `join` instead:

> Because any() uses a correlated subquery, its performance is not nearly as good when compared against large target tables as that of using a join.

In your case, you could do something like:

```
users = (
    session.query(ZKUser)
    .join(user_groups)
    .filter(user_groups.columns.group_id.in_([1, 2, 3]))
)
```

This emits SQL like:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
JOIN user_groups ON users.id = user_groups.user_id 
WHERE user_groups.group_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in_`:

```
session.query(ZKUser).filter(ZKGroup.id.in_([1,2])).all()
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot when I get back to the office after the weekend.  This looks promising.  Also, I like the coincidence of my class names and your username. :)  My "ZK" stands for Zookeeper, the name of my app. It interfaces with MailChimp's API.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.  I think it's because this isn't doing an actual join, so the SQL that gets emitted by this doesn't actually filter out the non-matching users.  I've checked out the docs on SQLAlchemy for doing joins on many-to-many tables, but I'm totally lost.

Comment: You could try doing `session.query(ZKUser).join(ZKGroup).filter(..)`. It should work in 0.7.2, afaik.

Comment: `NotImplementedError: in_() not yet supported for relationships.  For a simple many-to-one, use in_() against the set of foreign key values.` SQLAlchemy 1.3.18